# What is different between running a program directly and calling exec in script?

Tags: linux, exec

What is the difference between running a program with `exec` command or not ?

For instance, If I made a script file like below.

```
#script1
python test.py

#script2
exec python test.py
```

Both seem to return the same result.

Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`exec` is a shell built-in, which replaces the image of the current process with new process. It's not same as calling a binary/executable.

To see the difference, do:

```
#script1
python test.py
echo Hello

#script2
exec python test.py
echo Hello
```

You will not see the `Hello` getting printed in the second script.

`exec` also another purpose in shells. It can be used for redirection. For example,

```
exec 1>file
```

redirects the `stdout` of the process to `file`.

If you had:

```
exec 1>file
echo hello 
echo world
```

then script would redirect `hello` and `world` to `file` instead of `stdout`.